# Apache redirecting requests to port 23

Tags: apache-2.2, port

For some reason, Apache is redirecting all requests to port 23.. or maybe it isn't apache, but something is doing it.  This started happening randomly and for no apparently reason.. Anyone know what the problem could be? My users aren't getting error messages, it just says they can't connect.

Comment: What do you mean, 'redirecting'. Are users getting a 301 or 302 redirect response header when they do a request, with a Location that includes port 23?

Comment: Could you show the output of `sudo lsof -i :80`?

Comment: In configserver firewall it's saying that my server is trying to make outbound connection on port 23.  i have verified the user's IP addresses who are having trouble with it so I know it isn't a malicious attempt.

Comment: @Tar You'll need to provide more information than that.  Why would an outbound connection on a port assigned to a completely non-HTTP-related protocol be correlated in your firewall logs to an HTTP request made by a remote client?

Comment: That is why I'm asking.  It hasn't happened before.  I have like 1,300 connection doing `netstat -ntu | wc -l` all on TIME_WAIT

Comment: @Tar Can you provide the log entries, details about how you determined that the HTTP requests are related in some way to the tcp/23 connections, and details about those outbound telnet connections?  We need some hard information if we're going to do any better than guessing.

Comment: If I'm going to guess without hard information, I'd guess that you have had some kind of server-side script injected into your site that is opening outbound telnet connections whenever the script is loaded.  Where are these port 23 connections going to? All one place?

Comment: http://screensnapr.com/e/CTm2lP.png  

Pic of the iptables logs.. it's happening again.  I can't provide any correlation between port 80/port 23.  Lots of other people are able to access the site without any problem.  I know that it is a problem because with the IP of a user I see that the server was attempting an outbound connection to port 23 on their host when they were simply trying to access the site.

Comment: Also there is nothing in apache error log to suggest that a script injection is at fault.. Only errors in there are 404s because of some favicons that i haven't updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my first check would be iptables... it is probably forward port 80 requests to port 23.

`iptables -nL -v --line-numbers | grep "ACCEPT" | egrep <port number>`

Also have a look at what ports your server is listening on. It should say listening on port 80  like so

`tcp        0      0 <ip>:81             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN`

`netstat -an | grep LISTEN | egrep "80"`

`netstat -an | grep LISTEN | egrep "23"`

you can quickly disable iptables, this will confrim if it is iptables. Normally:

`/etc/init.d/iptables stop`